# How to change default gateway for deluge

Tags: networking

I have two network interfaces:

```bash
 $ ip route
default via 192.168.43.1 dev wlp0s20f3 proto dhcp metric 600 
default via 192.168.55.1 dev wlx00e020306060 proto dhcp metric 601 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp0s20f3 scope link metric 1000 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-7c842c08107b proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.43.0/24 dev wlp0s20f3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.43.143 metric 600
```

For all of the tasks, I want to use 192.168.43.1 as the gateway.  However, for the `deluge` program I want to use 192.168.55.1.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (`#` implies escalated privileges):

```
# ip route add default via 192.168.55.1 dev wlx00e020306060 table deluge
# ip rule add fwmark 1 table deluge
# iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 8112 -j MARK --set-mark 1
# ip route flush cache
```

This creates a new routing table called `deluge`, sets a rule to use this table for packets marked with the value of `1`, and uses iptables to mark the packets sent to deluge's port (8112) with the value `1`.

To remove the rule:

```
# ip route delete default via 192.168.55.1 dev wlx00e020306060 table deluge
# ip rule del fwmark 1 table deluge
# iptables -t mangle -D OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 8112 -j MARK --set-mark 1
# ip route flush cache
```